# How to Implement Pagination with Laravel Collections?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection, laravel-pagination

As far as I know that Laravel pagination doesn't work with Laravel collections (Eloquent). For example:

```
$articles = Article::with('category')->where('status', 'submitted')->get();
```

I'm trying to make pagination with above code snipped but  `where('status', 'submitted')` is not working.

**Controller**

```
$articles = Article::paginate(10);
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($articles->with('category')->where('status', 'submitted') as $article)
    { ... }
    {{ $articles->links() }}
```

I am getting an error.

Comment: Add the with/where before your pagination clause. Basically, take the first bit of code, and trade get for paginate.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paginate the query after your where clause:

```
$articles = Article::with('category')->where('status', 'submitted')->paginate(10);
```

In your blade:

```
{{ $articles->links() }}

@foreach($articles as $article)
    { ... }
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked and I understood what to do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Remul's answer, if you still want to paginate a collection, you could do that with the [forPage()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-forpage) method. For example:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);

$chunk = $collection->forPage(2, 3); 
// first argument is the page number 
// second one is the number of items to show per page

$chunk->all();
```