# How to display pagination links in a blade on Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, pagination

I need to add pagination, but it seems complicated in my case, because I get data from database with paginate, but then I modify this data and when I call `links()` method on the blade, I get the following exception
**Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist.**
My code in the Controller method:

```php
$transactionsByLastMonth = Transaction::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->toDateTimeString())
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->with(['user', 'propertyFrom', 'propertyTo', 'paddockFrom', 'paddockTo', 'cattleTypeFrom', 'cattleTypeTo'])
    ->paginate(10);
        
$transactionsByDays = collect(TransactionResource::collection($transactionsByLastMonth))
    ->sortByDesc('created_at')
    ->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date['created_at'])->format('d');
    });

return view('user.reports.index', compact('transactionsByDays'));
```

Yes, a pagination limits my data to 10 rows, but due to I'm grouping data by days, my collection modifies itself and I can't use `$transactionsByDays->links()` method to show pagination.
If see `dd($transactionsByDays)` , it looks like:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1381 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "01" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1019 ▼
      #items: array:7 [▼
        0 => array:16 [▶]
        1 => array:16 [▶]
        2 => array:16 [▶]
        3 => array:16 [▶]
        4 => array:16 [▶]
        5 => array:16 [▶]
        6 => array:16 [▶]
      ]
    }
    31 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1386 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => array:16 [▶]
        1 => array:16 [▶]
      ]
    }
    30 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1384 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => array:16 [▶]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Therefore I need to paginate all arrays together which inside "01", 31, 30...
How can I do it?
Maybe rewrite code above in the controller somehow?
The main aim is that I need to group data to every day according to my json-resource class.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Implement Pagination with Laravel Collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182924/how-to-implement-pagination-with-laravel-collections)

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai , It would be too easy if true. Actually I've already found a solution. Shortly speaking, I had to pass a variable with ```paginate()``` method and also pass a grouped variable to my view. Then use ```links()``` method on the first variable, but iterate data by foreach on the second variable (grouped). I originally tried to use ```links()``` on the second (grouped) variable and it did not work, this was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution gyus. I had to pass also a variable `transactionsByLastMonth` and use `links()` method over this.
In the meantime I use foreach on the my blade file over `transactionsByDays` variable. It's correctly works together cause it uses the same data from database, just in the first case its not filtered and not grouped and in the second one it is.

```php
return view('user.reports.index', compact('transactionsByLastMonth', 'transactionsByDays'));
```